# Combine both present perfect and simple past together

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

Is it correct to combine both present perfect and simple past together as in the sentence below?

> This method has saved the lives of many patients as the true diagnosis was missed or unusual.

Comment: *As* is a little wonky, but the sentence  is fine. The method brought about the present state ("has saved lives") because (presumably) it negated the effects of the past errors.

Answer (score 1):

The first phrase indicates a repeat occurrence. The second phrase is merely an explanation of the reason why.
Since it (the wrong diagnosis) would have already occurred (which led to the "method"), this construction is OK.

However I think this would read more naturally with "because" instead of *as" since it is an explanation:

> This method has saved the lives of many patients **because** the true diagnosis was missed or unusual.